# Populate UserForm Combo Boxes with default values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

TierStructureTierStructureI am trying to populate two comb boxes on a userform w/ VBA and set a default value for the same boxes based on a ws function. I think I can figure out the ws function, but I'm having a little trouble with arrays and the default values.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim TierStructure() As Variant

TierSturucture = Array("Composite", "2-Tier", "3-Tier", "4-Tier", "5-Tier", "6-Tier")

StopLossCombo.List = TierSturucture 
AdminCombo.List = TierSturucture 
StopLossCombo.Value = TierStructure(1)
AdminCombo.Value = TierStructure(1)

End Sub
```

The error I receive is "run time error 9 - subscript out of range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo - "TierSturucture" in two places.

To avoid this in the future, make sure each module has "Option Explicit" at the top. You can automate this via Tools>Options>Editor>Require Variable Declaration. This will make sure any variable has been declared, and thereby catch misspellings.

Also, note that you don't need to declare TierStructure as an array. Variant variables can hold arrays by themselves. So, just use:

```
Dim TierStructure As Variant
```

Comment: Thank You!! I thought I had copied and pasted to avoid any typos, but I guess I missed that one.